# How to implement "Alarm" by UILocalNotification?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uilocalnotification

I want to implement Alarm by UILocalNotification. I am doing first time it. I have no idea how  i do it. please anyone help me..thank you

Comment: NSLocalNotification only works for OSX ,but your tag is iPhone and iOS,May be you should have a look at UILocalNotification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-scheduling-local-notifications-using-a-singleton-class/) is a good tutorial about this.